# Removing mysql-common removes some unrelated packages

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

```
$ sudo apt remove mysql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant ant-optional blender-data colord-data dialign digikam-data emboss-data fonts-dejavu gdal-data gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 hplip-data java-wrappers libactivation-java
  libaec0 libaopalliance-java libapache-pom-java libargs4j-java libarmadillo9 libarpack2 libasm-java libastro1 libatinject-jsr330-api-java libavresample-dev libbarclay-java
  libbatik-java libbiojava-java libbiojava1.7-java libblas-dev libblosc1 libbytecode-java libbz2-dev libcaf-openmpi-3 libcdi-api-java libcglib-java libcharls2
  libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcodemodel-java libcolorhug2 libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java
  libcommons-io-java libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-math3-java libcommons-net-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java
  libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libdap25 libdapclient6v5 libdc1394-22-dev libdcmtk14 libdom4j-java libdtd-parser-java libepsilon1 libexif-dev libexif-doc libfabric1
  libfastinfoset-java libfreemarker-java libfreexl1 libfyba0 libgatk-native-bindings-java libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdcm-dev libgdcm3.0 libgeos-3.8.0 libgeos-c1v5
  libgeotiff5 libgeronimo-annotation-1.3-spec-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libgkl-java libgkl-jni libgl2ps1.4 libgoogle-gson-java libgphoto2-dev
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12 libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev libguava-java libguice-java
  libhawtjni-runtime-java libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103 libhdf5-openmpi-103 libhpdf-2.3.0 libhsqldb-java libhtml-template-perl libhtsjdk-java libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java
  libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc15 libibatis-java libibverbs-dev libieee1284-3 libieee1284-3:i386 libilmbase-dev libistack-commons-java libj2ssh-java libjansi-java
  libjansi-native-java libjaxb-api-java libjaxb-java libjaxen-java libjemalloc2 libjoptsimple-java libjsoup-java libjsr305-java libkf5akonadi-data libkf5akonadicontact-data
  libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5abi2 libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2 libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1 libkf5calendarcore5abi2 libkf5contacteditor5
  libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2 libkf5sane-data libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 liblapack-dev liblensfun-data-v1 liblensfun1 liblightcouch-java liblog4j1.2-java
  liblog4j2-java libmarblewidget-qt5-28 libmaven-file-management-java libmaven-parent-java libmaven-resolver-java libmaven-shared-io-java libmaven-shared-utils-java
  libmaven3-core-java libmecab2 libmongodb-java libnetcdf-c++4 libnetcdf15 libnghttp2-14:i386 libngs-java libngs-sdk-dev libngs-sdk2 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libnuma-dev
  libogdi4.1 libopencv-core-dev libopencv-core4.2 libopencv-dnn-dev libopencv-dnn4.2 libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-flann4.2 libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc4.2
  libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ml4.2 libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo4.2 libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-viz-dev libopencv-viz4.2 libopenexr-dev libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3
  libopenvdb6.2 libosdcpu3.4.0 libosdgpu3.4.0 libpci3:i386 libperl5.30:i386 libpicard-java libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-interpolation-java libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils2-java libpmix2 libpostgresql-jdbc-java
  libpq5 libproj15 libprotobuf17 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2 libqhull7 libqtav1 libqtavwidgets1 libraw1394-dev libraw1394-tools librcc0 librcd0 libreadline-dev
  librelaxng-datatype-java librngom-java librtmp1:i386 libsane-common libservlet-api-java libshp2 libsidutils0 libsisu-guice-java libsisu-inject-java libsisu-ioc-java
  libsisu-plexus-java libslf4j-java libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni libsnmp-base libsocket++1 libspatialite7 libspnav0 libsquish0 libssh-4:i386 libstax-ex-java
  libstreambuffer-java libsuperlu5 libsz2 libtagc0 libtbb-dev libtbb2 libtxw2-java liburiparser1 libvtk6.3 libwagon-http-java libwagon-provider-api-java libx32gcc1
  libxerces-c3.2 libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxnvctrl0 libxsom-java libxz-java marble-plugins marble-qt-data mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
  mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 opencv-data openmpi-bin openmpi-common primer3 printer-driver-postscript-hp proj-bin proj-data
  python3-numpy python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel r-base-core r-base-dev r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-codetools r-cran-foreign
  r-cran-kernsmooth r-cran-lattice r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial r-cran-survival r-doc-html r-recommended
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  artemis* blender* colord* digikam* digikam-private-libs* emboss* emboss-lib* hplip* jemboss* kolourpaint* libgdal26* libhpmud0* libkf5sane5* libmysqlclient21*
  libopencv-calib3d4.2* libopencv-contrib4.2* libopencv-features2d4.2* libopencv-highgui4.2* libopencv-imgcodecs4.2* libopencv-objdetect4.2* libopencv-shape4.2*
  libopencv-stitching4.2* libopencv-superres4.2* libopencv-video4.2* libopencv-videoio4.2* libopencv-videostab4.2* libopenimageio2.1* libqt5sql5-mysql* libsane*
  libsane-hpaio* libsnmp35* mysql-client-8.0* mysql-common* printer-driver-hpcups* python3-opencv* sane-utils*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 36 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 275 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

How can you remove the package without removing all of the above?

Answer (score 0):

There is thing thig called as dependency. When you install a software, it might depend on some other extra package to provide some system calls or some service. When you remove this software, and the extra packages are no longer needed by any software, then it is safe to remove these packages also.

In your case, when it says `following packages were automatically installed`, it means these are the extra packages I mentioned earlier. So when you install a software, and its dependencies are not already present, it will install the dependencies `automatically`, and these dependencies are those automatically installed packages.

So, once you remove the main software, the automatically installed packages are no longer required. These packages can be removed using `sudo apt autoremove`. In the past you might have install one software which needs these `unrelated` packages you mentioned, but might not have run `sudo apt autoremove`, hence these are showing up now, as they are `automatically` installed but not `automatically` removed/uninstalled. You will have to do it manually.

Anyway, it is completely safe to remove these packages as the kernel says.

Just run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove those.